# GLSL broken access operator

Tags: opengl, glsl

I've been following a guide to learn OpenGL, and I'm now learning how to do post-processing.
In particular, I'm trying to apply a blur to my rendering through the following kernel:

$\frac{\begin{bmatrix}1&2&1\\2&4&2\\1&2&1\end{bmatrix}}{16}$

The problem I'm encountering is that whenever I try to access a float array's member through the `[]` operator giving it an int variable as parameter, it returns `0.0`.
Here's my fragment shader:

```
#version 410 core
in vec2 txcoords;  // Texture coordinates
out vec4 color;
uniform sampler2D tx;

const float offset = 1.0 / 300.0;

void main() {
    vec2 offsets[9] = vec2[](
        vec2(-offset,    offset),
        vec2( 0.0,       offset),
        vec2( offset,    offset),
        vec2(-offset,    0.0),
        vec2( 0.0,       0.0),
        vec2( offset,    0.0),
        vec2(-offset,   -offset),
        vec2( 0.0,      -offset),
        vec2( offset,   -offset)
    );

    const float kernel[9] = float[9](
        1.0 / 16, 2.0 / 16, 1.0 / 16,
        2.0 / 16, 4.0 / 16, 2.0 / 16,
        1.0 / 16, 2.0 / 16, 1.0 / 16
    );

    vec3 sampleTex[9];
    vec3 final = vec3(0.0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        sampleTex[i] = vec3(texture(tx, txcoords.st + offsets[i]));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        final += sampleTex[i] * kernel[i];
    }
    color = vec4(final, 1.0);
}
```

This code doesn't work(whole screen renders black), but if I change it to

```
final += sampleTex[i] * kernel[0];
```

then my scene is rendered correctly, but, of course, without any blur, just a bit darker than normal.
It also doesn't just work with `kernel[0]`, but with any number (`[1]`, `[2]`, etc.)

If instead I change it to

```
final += sampleTex[i] * (kernel[i] + 0.05);
```

then it renders exactly the same as with

```
final += sampleTex[i] * 0.05;
```

And that's why I ended up suspecting that it's the `[i]` part that just won't work, for whatever reason.

Does anyone have any idea as to why this is happening? I also tried with different shader versions (330, 400, etc.) but they all give the same result.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What OpenGL version are you using, and is it WebGL or a real program?

Comment: I'm using SDL2 to create a context for OpenGL 4.1. It's the regular version of OpenGL, not ES or WebGL

Comment: In your `kernel` array you divide `float` by `int`. I suspect that for some reason your compiler cast this to `int`instead of `float`  so information is lost and then to `float`.

Comment: Why don't you use the numerators from the kernel and divide the whole thing by 16.0 at the end just to see if it works?

Comment: I've tried both adding `.0` to the divisions by 16 and removing the division altogether, and even changing the kernel to another post-proc effect, but it still gives me the same results.
For now, my solution is to just unravel the loop and write all the steps manually. Would that be a good approach or a bad practice in a professional shader?

Comment: I would find that odd, but if it works where a loop doesn't, go for it! It could be a bug in the glsl compiler or something. I'd add a comment explaining why you're doing.

Comment: Minor optimization unrelated to your problem (but also circumventing it): your specific kernel can as well be achieved with just 4 texture accesses and an average of those 4 values. Just use a linearly filtered sampler and move the four texture coordinates by half a texel into the four corners of the current texel. You'll find that with normal linear filtering this will give you exactly the weighting specified in `kernel`.